# Kubernetes cni config uninitialized

Tags: kubernetes

I'm installing kubernetes(kubeadm) on centos VM runing inside `Virtualbox`, so with yum i installed `kubeadm, kubelet` and `docker`.

Now while trying to setup cluster with `kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.56.0/24 --apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.56.33/32` i run into the following error :

```
Unable to update cni config: No networks found in /etc/cni/net.d

Container runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized
```

So i checked, no `cni` folder in `/etc` even that `kubernetes-cni-0.6.0-0.x86_64` is installed. I Tried commenting `KUBELET_NETWORK_ARGS` in `/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf` but it didn't work.

PS:

- I'm installing behind proxy.
- I have multiple network adapters:

  - NAT : 10.0.2.15/24 for Internet
  - Host Only : 192.168.56.33/32
  - And docker interface : 172.17.0.1/16

> Docker version:  17.12.1-ce
>   kubectl version : Major:"1",
>   Minor:"9", GitVersion:"v1.9.3"
>   Centos 7

Comment: sorry, but the pod network is an overlay network and need to be different from your host only network

Comment: runing `kubeadm init` with no arguments return the same error

Comment: I am using kubernetes 1.9.3 and I used kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 and I used flannel as network addon

Answer (score 3):

It was a proxy error as mentionned in `Github` https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/34695

They suggested to use `kubeadm init --use-kubernetes-version v1.4.1` but i change my network entirely (no proxy) and i manage to setup my cluster.

And as @Radek mentionned before, seting up pod network with `kubectl apply -f ....` came after the initialization of cluster.

Answer (score 1):

`reason:NetworkPluginNotReady` - you need to install a networking solution into kubeadm provisioned cluster before anything else can start up.

[Using kubeadm to Create a Cluster - Installing a pod network | Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/#pod-network)

Comment: I'm having this error `The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?` In every execution of `kubectl`. Trying to install pod network (weave) with `kubectl apply -f ...` didn't work.

Comment: the error in your comment means that you probably have no valid config in ~/.kube/config (or it points to localhost:8080 and no api is there which is the less likely scenario)

Answer (score 1):

seems a docker image is missing.

#### check if the images have been downloaded into your machines(VM)

`docker image list` or `kubeadm config images list`

expected image: `quay.io/coreos/flannel v0.10.0-amd64`.

*pls refer to offical doc for more images required*

#### if the image is missing, pls download it manually.

`docker pull quay.io/coreos/flannel:v0.10.0-amd64`

for more images: `kubeadm config images pull`

Then, restart

Answer (score 0):

none of the above solutions didn't worked for me.
I found out that my server does not have default route!

```
# route -n
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp9s0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
```

so I added the default gateway by the following command:

```
# route add default gw 19.168.1.1
# route -n 
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp9s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp9s0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
```

right now the `iptables` works fine